# Bash script flag arguments not working when I use the script globally by placing it in /usr/local/bin

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have the following code. file name is vb.

```
#!/bin/bash

valid='/version/'
versionJson=""
bumpThis=""
bumped=""
while read line; do
if echo "$line" | grep '"version": '; then
 versionJson=$line
fi
done < package.json

version=$(echo "$versionJson" | sed -e 's/"version": "\(.*\)",/\1/')
IFS='.'; splitVersion=($version); unset IFS;

while [[ "$1" =~ ^- && ! "$1" == "--" ]]; do case $1 in
  -m | -minor )
    bumpThis=${splitVersion[1]}
    bumped="\"version\": \"${splitVersion[0]}.$((bumpThis + 1)).${splitVersion[2]}\","
    ;;
  -M | -major )
    bumpThis=${splitVersion[0]}
    bumped="\"version\": \"$((bumpThis + 1)).${splitVersion[1]}.${splitVersion[2]}\","
    ;;
  -p | -patch )
    bumpThis=${splitVersion[2]}
    bumped="\"version\": \"${splitVersion[0]}.${splitVersion[1]}.$((bumpThis + 1))\","
    ;;
  *)
    bumpThis=${splitVersion[2]}
    bumped="\"version\": \"${splitVersion[0]}.${splitVersion[1]}.$((bumpThis + 1))\","
    ;;
esac; shift; done

if (( $OPTIND == 1 )); then
   echo no commands
   bumpThis=${splitVersion[2]}
   bumped="\"version\": \"${splitVersion[0]}.${splitVersion[1]}.$((bumpThis + 1))\","
fi

echo "new version: " $bumped
sed -i '' "s/$versionJson/$bumped/g" package.json
npm install
```

when I run the script inside the directory like `./vb -minor` it works fine. but if I place the file in /usr/local/bin and try to run `vb -minor` it does not pass in the flag and always runs the default behavior. what am I doing wrong? I tried creating a simple test script that just echos back an argument in /usr/local/bin it works fine.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you're referencing `OPTIND` but not calling `getopts`. Perhaps you have a stale value of `OPTIND=1` somewhere. Try doing `unset OPTIND; vb -minor`.

Comment: @MikeHolt that was the issue. I replaced by while loop to eval flags to use getopts and it is working now. thanks :)

Comment: I'd also recommend replacing all of the `grep`, `sed`, etc with something that actually knows how to parse and modify json, like `jq`.